# Problems with composer civicrm:publish

Tags: composer

I recently had an error becuase my **kcfinder** package was out of date. I fixed it by manually copying the `kcfinder` folder from `dir/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages` to `dir/html/libraries/civicrm/packages`. I had tried running `composer civicrm:publish` but it seems this command is not working as expected for me.

I have a slightly different structure in my project as follows:

```
    dir
    -html
    --libraries
    ---civicrm
    ----packages
    -vendor
    --civicrm
    ---civicrm-packages
```

so in my root composer.json I have:

```
"civicrm-asset": {
            "path": "html/libraries/civicrm",
            "url": "/libraries/civicrm"
        },
```

When I run `composer civicrm:publish`, it looks like it runs fine, I get the message:

```
Publishing CiviCRM assets to html/libraries/civicrm
Generating CiviCRM asset map
```

however, no new files seem to get written to the packages folder `html/libraries/civicrm/packages`. I tried changing the `civicrm-asset` paths in my `composer.json` file to:

```
 "civicrm-asset": {
            "path": "html/libraries/civicrm/packages",
            "url": "/libraries/civicrm/packages"
        },
```

Then this generates a new folder `packages` inside the existing `html/libraries/civicrm/packages` folder and has copied across the libraries. However, it doesn't copy all the files, it doesn't seem to copy some of the folders or any of the `.php` files.

I am recently now also getting an error on my status page:

> Wrong version of assets in public web directory: expected 5.70.0 but found 5.69.4

I checked the permissions on the `html/libraries/civicrm/packages` folder and they seem to be fine so not sure what the problem is. I also thought it would be useful to view the generated CiviCRM asset map, but wasn't sure how to do this.

Comment: I think your original config was fine. Try the `-D` [option](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/blob/88c7dd0c93b6b5a4453a63e523706c941086763b/src/Command/CivicrmPublishCommand.php#L21) to do a complete copy. But note that (a) the plugin isn't supposed to copy everything, just web assets, and (b) kcfinder is known to have problems with drupal 8+. Consider using [summernote](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/summernote) as your editor instead.

Comment: Thanks so much @Demerit, the -D option worked, all the packages were copied over. I should have known there would have been some command options! Thanks also for the tip on summernote, although kcfinder is working ok at the moment even with Drupal 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments the `-D` [option](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/blob/88c7dd0c93b6b5a4453a63e523706c941086763b/src/Command/CivicrmPublishCommand.php#L21) cleared out the cobwebs.

Comment: Same issue for me after a Civicrm upgrade: "Wrong version of assets in public web directory: expected 5.71.1 but found 5.70.2." Numerous attempts at `composer civicrm:publish` didn't work until I added the `-D` option. Thanks for the tip @Demerit.